# Case WHEN error

Tags: mysql, sql, database

this is my query

```
CASE
    WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table` WHERE `ip`= 'myip' )=1 
        THEN UPDATE `table`
        SET `last_active`=".date("Ymd").",`last_time`=".date("His")."
        WHERE `ip`= 'myip';

    ELSE (INSERT INTO `table`(ip)
        VALUES("myip"));

        END
```

but its not woking .the problem should be from here

```
 (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table` WHERE `ip`= 'myip' )=1
```

how can I fix this ? or how to do this another way?

the date("Ymd") function is just the php function to return the date the problem isnt from that

thanks

Comment: A query starts with `SELECT` (or perhaps `UPDATE` or `DELETE` or `REPLACE`).  Show the full query or descrdibe what you are tyring to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to do this:

```
create unique index unq_table_ip on table(ip);

insert into table (ip)
    values ('myip')
    on duplicate key update last_active = curdate(),
                            last_time = curtime();
```

The unique index (or equivalently a unique constraint) guarantees that a given `ip` only appears once in the table.  Let the database do this work for you -- this is called maintaining relational integrity.

Notes:

- This assumes that `last_active` and `last_time` have default values in the table.
- You should use the database time, not the application time for this purpose (after all, different clients could have different time values).
- You should probably put the date/time values into a single `datetime` column, say `last_active_datetime`.

Answer (score 1):

Define unique constraint on `ip` column and then use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`:

```
insert into `table` (ip) values ("myup") 
on duplicate key update 
`last_active`=".date("Ymd").",`last_time`=".date("His")."
```